# layout-land concept not working in case of landscape mode

Tags: android

I am making an app in which i want to put different layouts for landscape as well as portrait mode of the view.I have made a separate folder layout-land for that purpose but when i move the device to landscape mode,its not working.Please tell me the solution.

This is the activity:

```
package com.example.fragmenttest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

This is the xml file for this activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        />

     <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="a1501e5633125fb"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, 123456789ABCDEF" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the xml of the layout in layout-land folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    >
   <TextView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="This is fragment 2 "   
    /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do both the xml files have the same name?

Comment: code working very fine...

have you added the library of google adds..??
or all the fields are true..???
check it only else code working fine...

Comment: No the name of the xml files is different

Comment: The problem is that even in the landscape mode,the xml in the layout-land folder is not working and the view remains the same as of portrait mode

Comment: Both the file name must be same .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change that landscape file name to `activity_main` . Both the file name must be same .